# Hide an overflowing navigation, but still show dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site that requires a "double" navigation bar. I would like to show the active nav within a space, hiding the inactive navigation, and animate the new nav bar in when the user chooses to toggle it.

I have a JSfiddle here to help visualize the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/j8wyeazv/7/

Note that my dropdowns do extend further left than the container, so `overflow-x` is not an option.

edit: I should mention, the dropdowns have been simplified in the JSFiddle, the actual dropdowns will be multiple columns of links, and will extend further left and right than the "parent" link.

Comment: Sorry about that. Should have made it a bit more obvious but in the JS fiddle I have a CSS comment showing the overflow line that hides the drop down (and the second nav).

Comment: This article may help you https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How my code needs to be built, I may have posed an impossibility (without more JS). I ended up just settling for no overflow, and just fading the element's `opacity` to 0 when inactive.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j8wyeazv/8/

Thanks to the two great solutions from Roko C. Buljan and cespon. Both of those solutions would likely work under different requirements, so I encourage others to take a look at those solutions!

Answer (score -1):

Set the main UL element to `overflow:hidden`, but let it *breathe in height* as the submenu items appear.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/nexugi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

The trick to achieve what you want is by simply:
**not have any `position:absolute` element inside your menu**

otherwise the **overflowed** `UL` menu will **loose height** showing unwanted vertical scrollbars (if set to `overflow-x:hidden`) or none (if set to `overflow:hidden;`)
***and we'll be unable to ever see the submenu items***.

**Height** on the overflowed menu element → **is exactly what we need**:

```
+-----------------------+
| HELLO WORLD     <btn> |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+ < NAV containing our UL
| LINK1 | LINK2 | LINK3 | LINK4 | LINK5 | LINK6 |
|       |  SUB1 |               |  SUB1 |       |
|       |  SUB2 |               +-------+       |
+-------+-------+-------------------------------+ < UL height == tallest submenu
| Lorem ipsum pageus    |
| contentis maximus     |
| stachius overflovius. |
```

the above is simply achieved using LI as `inline-block` elements inside a parent where `white-space: nowrap;` on the UL parent allows the LI children to extend horizontally (without wrapping).

***"But now the menu height is too tall!"***
no problem, set the `<nav>` parent height to i.e: `height:40px;`

```
+-----------------------+
| HELLO WORLD     <btn> |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+ < NAV height : 40px
| LINK1 | LINK2 | LINK3 | LINK4 | LINK5 | LINK6 | 
+       |  SUB1 |               |  SUB1 |       |
|       |  SUB2 |               +-------+       | < Page content is now underneath!
+-------+-------+-------------------------------+ 
| stachius overflovius. |
|                       |
|                       |
```

***Almost there! let's hide the submenu items***
Setting any `li > ul` submenu to `overflow:hidden and height:0;` will result in:

```
+-----------------------+
| HELLO WORLD     <btn> |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+ 
| LINK1 | LINK2 | LINK3 | LINK4 | LINK5 | LINK6 | 
+-----------------------------------------------+ < LI UL submenu to height 0
| Lorem ipsum pageus    |
| contentis maximus     |
| stachius overflovius. |
|                       |
|                       |
```

currently your window should have horizontal scrollbars cause the list elements extend too much to the right...

**Finally set that `overflow:hidden`to the main `UL` element**

```
+-----------------------+
| HELLO WORLD     <btn> |
+-----------------------+
| LINK1 | LINK2 | LINK3 | 
+-----------------------+
| Lorem ipsum pageus    |
| contentis maximus     |
| stachius overflovius. |
|                       |
|                       |
```

**MENU LIST HOVER: reveal the submenu setting it's `height` to `auto`**

`nav li:hover > ul{ height:auto; }`

```
+-----------------------+
| HELLO WORLD     <btn> |
+-----------------------+
| LINK1 | LINK2 | LINK3 | < ON HOVER : submenu height to auto!
+-------|  SUB1 |-------+
| Lorem |  SUB2 |eus    |
| conten+-------+us     |
| stachius overflovius. |
|                       |
|                       |
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/nexugi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Comment: Very detailed response, and I appreciate all the hard work you put in to spell it out so plainly with images, but the main reason my dropdowns need to be position absolute is because their width will be much larger than that of their parents (multiple columns of links).

Comment: @BrianJohn than simply retrieve with JS the position of the parent LI and showcase the absolute submenu where needed. I don't think otherwise it'll be possible in pure CSS.